# Compare decimal number for a given precision

Tags: python, decimal

I'm trying to compare two coordinates. The idea is that two coordinates are "the same" if they have equal values up to 5 decimals.

That means:

```
Decimal(45.00001) =/= Decimal(45.00002)
Decimal(45.000001) == Decimal(45.000002)
```

because the first 5 decimals are the same

Is there a built in way to do that or do I need to do a string splitting and comparison?

Comment: convert to string and compare.

Comment: Is `44.99999` the same as `45.00000`? String comparisons seem much less reliable than simply e.g. `abs(x-y) < 0.000005`

Comment: @JohnColeman Oh yes, abs difference is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to use `Decimal` for this at all, unless you have other reasons for doing so.  Just define an epsilon value, then do `abs(a-b) <= epsilon` to compare them.

Comment: What about `round(a * 1e5) == round(b * 1e5)`?

Comment: better to use `round(a, 5)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things you can do with `Decimal`:

```py
from decimal import Decimal, localcontext

ax = Decimal(45.00001)
ay = Decimal(45.00002)
bx = Decimal(45.000001)
by = Decimal(45.000002)

# 1. using a local context with given precision
with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 7
    a_tst = ax.normalize() == ay.normalize()
    b_tst = bx.normalize() == by.normalize()
>>> a_tst, b_tst
(False, True)

# 2. using the Python built-in round()
# (which also works on native floats and ints
k = 5
a_tst = round(ax, k) == round(ay, k)
b_tst = round(bx, k) == round(by, k)
>>> a_tst, b_tst
(False, True)
```

Note: the `localcontext()` version is cumbersome, because `prec` refers to the full precision (all digits), not just the number of digits after the decimal point.  I'd recommend going with `round(x, k)`.

Why did I say that round works on floats *and ints*? You can use `round(x, k)` with negative `k`:

```py
>>> round(54321, -2)
54300
```

BTW, I'm not sure why you are using `Decimal`. If you are dealing with lots of coordinates, you may want to use `numpy`. When using `numpy`, the canonical way to compare values (single scalars or vectors or tensors of any compatible dimension) is with `np.allclose(x, y)`. You can customize the precision of the comparison, for example, in your case, you could say:

```py
import numpy as np

prec = 0.5e-5
a_tst = np.allclose(float(ax), float(ay), rtol=0, atol=prec)
b_tst = np.allclose(float(bx), float(by), rtol=0, atol=prec)
>>> a_tst, b_tst
(False, True)
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. According to the "why I use decimal" - The `lat` and `lng` are Django model's fields. I rather use decimal than float to keep the precision.